# CSVexporter fails when a legend is added to the plotWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm creating a charter using pyqtgraph. To  export the data, I'm using pyqtgraph's built-in `CSVExporter()` to export csv files. However, I also tried to add a legend, it fails.

Interestingly enough, the legend can exist on its own, and everything works fine. From my understanding, the legend actually starts being filled in with the names of the curves when you add the `name` parameter when instantiating each `PlotItem`. This is when the exporter fails.

I have a running list of `PlotItem` objects and instantiate them as so:

```
plot = self.plotWidget.plot(self.data[i], pen=(i, self.data.size), name=i)  
self.traces.append(plot)
```

I get the following error only when the legend has data filled in. That is, only when it displays something like

"curve 1"
"curve 2"

```
File "app.py", line 335, in saveData
    exporter.export(fileName='data.csv')
File "/Users/sammyalhashemi/Documents/Charter/python-gui/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtgraph/exporters/CSVExporter.py", line 44, in export
name = c.name().replace('"', '""') + '_'
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: provider a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, I actually figured it out. It occurs because when instantiating a PlotItem, for example when you call `plotWidget.plot(data, pen, name)`, there is no check that the `name` parameter must be a string. As a test, I was plugging in `int`s, and thus the exporter was looking at integer names, and hence the above error. I think this an extra check should be added to pyqtgraph, or at least make it more clear in the docs.